# Pulling columns based on values in a row

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I am looking for a way to use the values in the first row to help filter values I want. Say if I want to keep certain columns in R based on the values in the first row. So in the first row, we have -0.5, 0.7, 1.1, and -1.2.

I want to only keep values that are equal to or greater than 1, or less than or equal to -1.2. Everything else will just be dropped.

So say my original data I have is DF1

| ID | Location | XPL | SNA | AAS | APA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | Park | -0.5 | 0.7 | 1.1 | -1.2 |
| Second | School | 2 | 5 | 2 | 3 |
| Second | Home | 4 | 5 | 6 | 4 |
| Third | Car | 1 | 8 | 8 | 5 |
| Third | Lake | 7 | 5 | 4 | 6 |
| Fourth | Prison | 4 | 5 | 1 | 7 |

With the filter, I would now have a new DF:

| ID | Location | AAS | APA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | Park | 1.1 | -1.2 |
| Second | School | 2 | 3 |
| Second | Home | 6 | 4 |
| Third | Car | 8 | 5 |
| Third | Lake | 4 | 6 |
| Fourth | Prison | 1 | 7 |

What would be the best way for this. I feel there is a way to sort columns based on values from a row, but I am unable to think of the way we can with certain commands.

```
ID <- c("First", "Second", "Second", "Third", "Third", "Fourth")
Location <- c("Park", "School", "Home", "Car", "Lake", "Prison")
XPL <- c(-0.5,2,4,1,7,4)
SNA <- c(0.7,5,5,8,5,5)
AAS <- c(1.1,2,6,8,4,1)
APA <- c(-1.2,3,4,5,6,7)
DF1 <- data.frame(ID, Location, XPL, SNA, AAS,APA)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `dplyr`, you can `select` `numeric` columns whose `first` `abs`olute value is above 1:

```r
library(dplyr)
DF1 %>% 
  select(!where(~ is.numeric(.x) && abs(first(.x)) <= 1))

#       ID Location AAS  APA GOP
# 1  First     Park 1.1 -1.2 1.4
# 2 Second   School 2.0  3.0 1.0
# 3 Second     Home 6.0  4.0 2.0
# 4  Third      Car 8.0  5.0 2.0
# 5  Third     Lake 4.0  6.0 3.0
# 6 Fourth   Prison 1.0  7.0 3.0
```

Or with `between`:

```r
DF1 %>% 
  select(!where(~ is.numeric(.x) && between(first(.x), -1.19, 0.99)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the first row as the basis, you can convert it to a normal `integer` vector and use the `which` function to know the indexes that will be kept.

```
test.row <- as.numeric(DF1[1,3:6])
```

the `3` and `6` corresponds to the range of index from `XPL` to `APA`.

```
DF1 <- DF1[,c(1:2, 2 + which(test.row >= 1 | test.row <= -1.2))]
```

we keep the columns `ID` and `Location` as `1:2` and we offset `2` to the `which` function.

Comment: Thank you! If I had more columns, like thousands more, how would I adjust the code:

```
DF1 <- DF1[,c(1:2, 2 + which(test.row >= 1 | test.row <= -1.2))]
```

Thanks!

Comment: if you have multiple columns, it will depend on setting up `test.row` where you can pass from the 3rd column to the end `test.row <- as.numeric(DF1[1,3:ncol(DF1)])`